# Electron won't open file from JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, electron

I'm trying to use the onclick='shell.openItem('filename') with the filename being populated by JSON.  When I console.log(data[i].url) it returns the correct kmz file for each button, but when I click on the button it says Uncaught Reference Error: filename.kmz is not defined.

Thoughts on what I'm missing?  Thanks.

```
var portsbtn = document.getElementById("portsbtn");

portsbtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ourRequest.open('GET', 'jsonclean.json');
    ourRequest.onload = function() {
        var ourData = JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText);
        renderHTML(ourData[23]);
    };
    ourRequest.send();
});

//WRITE HTML FROM JSON ON BUTTON CLICK


function renderHTML(data) {
    var htmlString = "";
    $('#aceCategory').empty();
    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

        htmlString += "<p class='categoryName'>" + data[i].category + "</p>" + "<tr>" + "<td class='feedDesc'>" + "<b>" + data[i].name +
            "</b>" + "<br>" + data[i].desc + "</br>" + "<br>" + "<input type='button' id='openBtn' style='border-radius: 25px; outline: none' value='Open Link' onclick='shell.openItem(" + data[i].url + ");'" + ">" + "</td>" +
            "</tr>"
        console.log(data[i].url)
    };
    aceFeedTable.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', htmlString)

}
```

Comment: Why on earth are you compositing strings into html? Build DOM nodes the normal, not-even-modern-anymore way using document.createElement, and compose and insert them with appendChild etc. and assign them event listeners using normal addEventListener. Don't use `onclick=` on the HTML  side when you're _already_ on the JS side of things. (Or, if you're using jQuery, do all this in jQuery. It has lots of useful functions for this)

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Comment: That would be the kind of thing a modern JS tutorial, and any modern jQuery tutorial, covers just fine. Plenty of those to be found with even a casual web search.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  Code below.

```
       htmlString += "<p class='categoryName'>" + data[i].category + "</p>" + "<tr>" + "<td class='feedDesc'>" + "<b>" + data[i].name +
            "</b>" + "<br>" + data[i].desc + "</br>" + "<br>" + "<input type='button' id='openBtn' style='border-radius: 25px; outline: none' value='Open Link' onClick='openWindow(\"" + data[i].url + "\" )' >" + "</td>" +
            "</tr>"

    };
    aceFeedTable.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', htmlString)
}

function openWindow(url) {
    shell.openItem(url);
    console.log(url);
}
```